# Sharing updated gensim model file between gunicorn workers

Tags: flask, gunicorn, gensim

I am trying to create an API using Gunicorn and Flask for calling a gensim model.

One of the endpoints would allow users to input new products into the model without any downtime. We achieve this using model.add and model.save.

As I understand it Gunicorn would load up the current model and distribute copies of it to the workers.

```
# Load both the item2vec and word2vec model
modelname = load_model_item2vec(modelpath)
word2vec_model = load_model_item2vec(word2vec_modelpath)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/update_model", methods=["POST"])
  ...
  model.add(entities=..., weights=vectors)
  model.save(model_path)
  ...
```

After saving the updated model, it only affects the copy of the model in the worker itself, unless I restart the Gunicorn master process itself.

Is there anyway to propagate the updated model file to all the workers without any downtime/ needing to restart Gunicorn ? Thanks

Comment: How are you restarting the Gunicorn master process? Have you tried sending the `HUP` signal to request a 'graceful restart', where the master process doesn't die, but it tries to let existing workers finish while launching new workers to replace them? (You could concievably even do this from within the one worker that received the `/update_model`, if it can discover the right PID to target.)